# Create a layer with some buttons working?

Tags: ios, uibutton, calayer

I have a UIImageView full screen, there are buttons above. These buttons, when pressed should open up a larger image that has buttons. A button to open a site and the other to close the image. I thought about using a layer to bring out the image, but nothing comes out, even if the button works.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
       [super viewDidLoad];
        self.bigImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SBS_visual_ok.jpg"]];
        self.bigImageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        //....

        self.buttonInternational =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [self.buttonInternational addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedInternational:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.buttonInternational.frame = CGRectMake (100, 100, 100, 100);
        //...

        [self.view addSubview:self.bigImageView];
        [self.bigImageView addSubview:self.buttonInternational];
  }
```

pressing the button I want to get a picture with some buttons, but does not come out even the image. I have imported

```
  -(void)pressedInternational:(id)sender{

     CALayer *layer =[CALayer layer];
     layer.frame = CGRectMake(300, 400, 300, 200);
     layer.contents =(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"International_Security_Service.png"].CGImage;

     [[self.bigImageView layer]addSublayer:layer]; 
     NSLog(@"The layer is %@", layer);
     //The layer is <CALayer: 0x757ba30>


   }
```

How do I put on a layer of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to use a CALayer? It would probably be easier to display another UIView, which can have images, buttons, whatever:

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 300.0)];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

which you can easily show / hide

```
[self.myView setHidden:YES];
```

or push a new view controller:

```
MyViewController *nextViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If necessary, you could apply animations to the display and removal of either of these.